# Bootstrap pull-right not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have problem with bootstrap class `pull-right`. My `span` is still floated left. So, I don't know why `pull-right` class not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Vojtěch Matras">
  <title>Admin Express Blogs&Magazines</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <span class="text-light">AdminPanel</span>
      <span class="text-light pull-right">[@role][@nickname]</span>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code works fine as is. Click on the [Run code snippet] button below the code in your question and you will see it working fine.

Comment: Clear cache and refresh.

Comment: Yeah I see, but in chrome  on server not workings. I have [@role][@nickname] left  next to adminpanel

Comment: @VojtaMatras Do you have a custom build, loading only a part of bootstrap ? Could you inspect your element and see if the class exists ?

Comment: @Rob its  not help

Comment: @Kangouroops I am not sure, if i understand the questions.
I load bootstrap from link in  <head>
Inspect do you think ctrl+shit+i?   https://ctrlv.cz/Ugfc

Comment: your are using pull right in wrong reference it should always be used in grid i think

Comment: @VojtaMatras, your navbar is a flex container, you could add this class justify-content-between to your navbar. You should read the bootstrap 4 docs

Comment: @Kangouroops thx it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first your version used `4.1.1` dose not contain any class selector like `pull-right` but `float-right`. Secondly it is happening for container `nav` `navbar-expand-md` selector which contains a CSS properties like `justify-content:flex-start;` so this is dose not matter you using `float: left/right;` You need override `justify-content:flex-start;` to `justify-content:space-between;` with current Bootstrap based markup structure, see below I added snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Vojtěch Matras">
  <title>Admin Express Blogs&Magazines</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .navbar-expand-md {
            justify-content:space-between;
        }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <span class="text-light">AdminPanel</span>
      <span class="text-light float-right">[@role][@nickname]</span>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class="float-right" instead of class = "pull-right" and let me know if it works.

Comment: Updated answer please try again

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a problem while using class="float-right". You should add `<div class="clearfix"></div>`